# How much does it cost to use GAE data source for some website like a business directory?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am going to create a web site or you may call it a web application as it is going to and I attempt to use GAE data store. However this website would be used by many people to search for companies, create profiles (accounts). I am not sure how much it is going to cost as there would be many requests to fetch companies profiles and create new profiles. So, I need some advice about my idea is it going to cost a lot ? Does GAE data store fits with this kind of websites and applications ?.

Thanks in advance for reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, to estimate the cost you need to answer some questions. What is the number of read and write operations you expect? How many entities will you be storing? What is the approximate size of each entity? With that values you could estimate the cost based on the current [pricing](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing).

You didn't write what your requirements are, but I think one of those would be scalability. Take a look at this excerpt from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/).

> The App Engine Datastore is a schemaless object datastore providing
>   robust, scalable storage for your web application, with no planned
>   downtime, atomic transactions, high availability of reads and writes,
>   strong consistency for reads and ancestor queries, and eventual
>   consistency for all other queries.

If this doen't feet your needs you can also use [Google Cloud Sql](http://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/).